# How to add a line break within echo in PHP?

Tags: php

I was trying to add a line break for a sentence, and I added `/n`  in following code.

```
echo "Thanks for your email. /n  Your orders details are below:".PHP_EOL;
echo 'Thanks for your email. /n  Your orders details are below:'.PHP_EOL;
```

For some reasons, the I got server error as the result. How do I fix it?

Comment: use backslash, this is not properly escaped character `\n`. But the server error is not related to this try, look into **apache log** and check `__(arg)` docu

Comment: `\n` is a line break. `/n` is not.  See more details in https://stackhowto.com/how-to-add-a-new-line-within-echo-in-php/

Answer (score 327, accepted):

`\n` is a line break. `/n` is not.

---

use of `\n` with

### **1. echo directly to page**

Now if you are trying to echo string to the page:

```
echo  "kings \n garden";
```

***output*** will be:

```
kings garden
```

you won't get `garden` in new line because PHP is a server-side language, and you are sending output as HTML, you need to  create line breaks in HTML. HTML doesn't understand `\n`. You need to use the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function for that.

What it does is:

> Returns string with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

```
echo  nl2br ("kings \n garden");
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vc7HJB)

```
kings
garden
```

> **Note** Make sure you're echoing/printing `\n` in double quotes, else it will be rendered literally as \n. because php interpreter parse string in single quote with concept of ***as is***

```
so "\n" not '\n'
```

### **2. write to text file**

Now if you echo to text file you can use just `\n` and it will echo to a new line, like:

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w+")  ;

$txt = "kings \n garden";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

output will be:

```
kings
 garden
```

Comment: Exapnding on the above. This works - example ->  echo "<html>"."\n"; or  echo "kings garden"."\n"; which adds a line break after the first line.  Google led me here when i wanted to add line breaks after the echo.

Comment: It was the single quotes (' ') that had prevented this from working for me--thanks for the note that double quotes only works!

Answer (score 34):

You have to use br when using echo , like this :

```
echo "Thanks for your email" ."<br>". "Your orders details are below:"
```

and it will work properly

Comment: That wont work for html docs

Comment: That wont work  when you are echoing them in a php/server side language file

Comment: This work exactly as I had hoped - thank you Maryam

Answer (score 15):

The new line character is `\n`, like so:

```
echo __("Thanks for your email.\n<br />\n<br />Your order's details are below:", 'jigoshop');
```

Comment: What is the prefix `__` (two underscores)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Its a function in some PHP frameworks to support internationalization. The original post used it which is why I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try \r\n for carriage return / line feed

Comment: The problem seems to be the forward slash, `/n` vs `\n`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on final webpage. I tried. The first answer does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994798/14172167