# How can I fix the menu on the implanted header?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, menu

So I am working on my website and every page contains a copy of the header, footer, menu.  I am switching it to pull the footer and header/menu from html files of their own. This is what I'm using. 
In `page.php` I have:

```
<?php include('header.html'); ?>
```

And in `header.html` I have the the Meta Tag, Title, Logo, and Menu. You can view the menu code below:

```
                <ul id="nav" class="main">
                    <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact" class="active">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And this is not important but here is my css:
    .nav {list-style:none; margin:0 0 1.5em 0;}

```
/*Add a class of centred/centered to create a centred nav.*/

#nav.main{
float: right;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0;
font-family:'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav.main li {display:inline; float:none;}

#nav.main a{
display:inline-block;
padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
border-radius: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
border-bottom: 2px solid #bbb;
color: #666;text-decoration:none; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin: 0 0 0em 0;  
}
#nav.main a:hover{color: ; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; background-color: #ffd27f; }

#nav.main a.active{color: #fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333; font-weight: bold; background-color: #FF8307; letter-spacing: 1px;}

#nav li span {display: block; font-size: 10px; color: #666; text-shadow: none; line-height: 8px;}
```

If I have it as active for all pages all pages will show up as Contact being active.  How do I make it so that it knows what page I'm on and does it itself? I was thinking maybe to use JavaScript but how would I do this?

**Note: This is just a simple `php` and `html` site.**

Edit:

I did what @barmar said but know it works but the menu loses its padding and alignment and it looks weird why is that? I attached images of before and after.

[image: Picture of new menu]

[image: Picture of old menu]

Edit Edit: My old menu looks like the code I have above. This is my new menu with the boilerplate that is still coming up wrong like in the image 2 above.

```
<?php 
function show_header($this_page) {
    $navs = array('index' => 'Home', 'media' => 'Pictures & Videos', 'about' => 'About Us', 'donate' => 'Donate', 'contact' => 'Contact');
    ?>
    <!-- boilerplate stuff here -->
    <ul id="nav" class="main">
    <?php
    foreach ($navs as $href => $text) {
        $active = $href == $this_page ? "class='active'" : '';
        echo "<li><a href='$href' $active>$text</a></li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- more boilerplate -->
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a hard-coded HTML file, use a PHP script, and have it define a function.

header.php:

```
function show_header($this_page) {
    $navs = array('index' => 'Home', 'about' => 'About Us', 'contact' => 'Contact');
    ?>
    <!-- boilerplate stuff here -->
    <ul id="nav" class="main">
    <?php
    foreach ($navs as $href => $text) {
        $active = $href == $this_page ? "class='active'" : '';
        echo "<li><a href='$href' $active>$text</a></li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- more boilerplate -->
    <?php
}
```

Then the page would contain:

```
<?php require("header.php");
      show_header("contact");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. God Bless You!! You can view my site [here](http://www.o4c.org) , although I am still doing the changes and they are not up. Happy Easter!  @Barmar

Comment: I actually have one problem I thought I could fix it but not.  The coding of this php menu actually messes up my menu padding and alignment is there a fix to keep original alignment and padding. Thanks @barmar

Comment: I'd have to see more details. There must be some difference in the boilerplate around the nav menu.

Comment: I added more detail in my question. I added the exact code I have now and above it is the exact code I had. Tell me if you need anything else.  I don't understand this whole boilerplate thing. How does it work. Because it is also removing a few other things from my site with this new menu code. Thanks.    @barmar

Comment: also this is the [link](http://www.o4c.org/donate) to the old version and this is the [link](http://www.o4c.org/donate.php) to the new as you can see if you resize your window the new version ruins the mobile menu, that is fully working on the old.

Comment: In the old version the nav DIV was inside `logoMobileTop`, which is inside `wrappertop`. In the new version it's after `wrappertop`. Everything needs to be in the same place in the DOM hierarchy, you just have to use this function to create it so it can add the `active` class.

Comment: Hey @barmar thank you for helping me so much. So I fixed the location of the nav DIV but know still missing the button padding?  It's still linked to the same exact style sheet. here is this difference in the two codes  [link to code](https://www.diffchecker.com/y5qkhay5)

Comment: for some reason it doesn't put nav Div under 'logoMobileTop' but its putting everything above it and below it. Like a glitch that does not want to include that php code.

Comment: The nav DIV will be shown where you **call** the function `show_header`, not where you **define** it. You're defining it inside `logoMobileTop`, but you're calling it later.

Comment: Why do you have the `show_header` function directly in your code in the first place? I thought the whole point was that it would be in `header.php`, so it could be loaded by all the different pages.

Comment: BTW, the lines with `boilerplate stuff here` were not intended to be copied literally. Those are comments, indicating where you should put the parts of the header that don't depend on which page you're loading it into.

Comment: Yeah 'show_header' isn't actually there i just put it together to compare the code and also wrote -donate.php starts here. I could just add a margin to the buttons but why is the old margin not there? @barmar

Comment: Like I said, you need to move the **call** to `show_header` to where you want the nav div to appear.

Comment: ok i moved `show_header` to `logoMobileTop` you could check the website links i provided in the comment above. But the margin still won't appear. What is glitching the margin between the menu buttons. By editing the css I am able to add margin and make it look like before. But why isn't it like that right now? Is there a thing I can do to fix this, instead of adding it? Thanks @barmar

Comment: ok thanks if you check my website it all works now thanks for your help. Just one thing stackoverflow won't let me ask anymore questions. How can I fix that. And please don't just answer with a link to that page I looked at it already. Thanks, God Bless You.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you're blocked, I'm not sure where to look for that.

Comment: Hey @barmar can I ask you a question?  Would you mind going to my profile and likeing some of my questions. Or voting up.  Because it says my questions are not liked so I can no ask more....  Thanks. God Bless.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this but as this question is tagged "javascript" the easiest method would be to start with some form of identifier in each li-tag in `ul#nav`, such as a unique 'class' or 'id' attribute. Then you can 'target' a specific element with a scripted function, and call that function from somewhere else in the content file.  Something like...

```
/* CSS : style anchor-tags if li-tag has class 'active' */
#nav li.active a {
    text-decoration:underline;
}


/* JavaScript : in the head-tag of 'header.html' */
function setActive(activeElement) {
    var navlist = document.getElementById('nav');
    var listtags = navlist.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var listLength = listtags.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        if (listtags[i].id === activeElement) {
            listtags[i].setAttribute('class','active');
        }
    }
}

/* OR JQuery : in the head-tag of 'header.html' */
function setActive(activeElement) {
    $('#'+activeElement).addClass('active');
}
// (this is why we love JQuery !)

/* HTML : in the body-tag of 'header.html' */
<ul id="nav" class="main">
    <li id="home"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then somewhere in your content file (perhpas you're php-including something like 'home.html', 'about.html', and/or 'contact.html') call the function thus...

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {setActive('about')};
</script>
```

...to make `<li id="about" class="active"> ... </li>` etc.

---

**Re updated question:** Where before you probably had your `<li>` tags on separate lines, padded in the document with some whitespace and/or tab-spaces, now your `<li>` tags butt up against each other without a break. Try adding an extra space at the end of...

```
echo "<li><a href='$href' $active>$text</a></li> "; // <-- extra space
```

...or add a line-break `"\n"` (See [Stackoverflow: How to add a line break within echo in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php)). And perhaps check your editor's preferences for handling whitespace and tab-spaces etc.