# converting \n to <br/> still prints out the <br/> instead of processing

Tags: javascript, php

Javascript Code

```
var contact_comments = $("#con_us_comment").val();
contact_comments = contact_comments.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
$.post('post.php', {'con_us_comment':contact_comment}, function(data) {
    // stuff i'm doing with reply from post call
}
```

PHP Code just takes the raw data coming from post and sends it through an email to me.

```
$contact_comment = test_input($_POST['con_us_comment']);
$body .= "<br/><b>Comments:  </b> ".$contact_comment;
```

Email sent with the body set as shown above

The email output looks like this:

```
Comments:  line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3
```

instead of:

```
Comments:  line 1
           line 2
           line 3
```

so it successfully replaces the \n but it doesn't process the 
 and instead shows it as text

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've also tried nl2br($contact_comment) on the PHP side and it doesn't even replace the \n

Comment: Does the email header have `Content-type: text/html`?

Comment: Then the email headers aren't set to text/html..

Comment: Email is plain text by default. If you're sending HTML, you need to say so in the header.

Comment: example 4 in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: I use PHPMailer and the variable mentioned above is being sent to a function I've created.  The $body variable has other <br/> in it that process just fine, its only the ones in this specific variable coming from the javascript $.post call.  small example:  function send_email ($body) will just add the $body into the already created template for the body of the email and that template has <br/> that process just fine.  I hope i'm explaining it properly.  It's just from 1 variable added into the body that the <br/> don't get processed.  my phpmailer is using $msgHTML($body) to create the email

Comment: check its not actully &lt;b/&gt;

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  I know that if I don't run my javascript variable through the .replace function then the email comes out with \n instead of <br /> so it appears to be \n coming from the <textarea>

I'm presuming &lt;b/&gt = <br /> ?

Comment: Maybe instead of using `<br />` do as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php) suggests and use the `nl2br()` function.

Comment: check the email source

Comment: @KevinFriedheim I tried that, doesn't replace the \n with anything. (see my first comment)

Comment: @Dragon  It IS showing up as that in the email source!!  Before I ask how to fix it i'll search for an answer

Comment: make sure your not calling htmlentities() on the string

Comment: have you tried `$body .= "<b>Comments:  </b> ".html_entity_decode($contact_comment, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` ?

Comment: html_entity_decode() worked.
I was focused on fixing the javascript side and the solution was on the php side.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-type: text/html in header of your mail script If you are using php mail() function then try adding

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

before your `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent html contents in mail,then you must add these headers.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```