# how can I implement a line break in a variable in php?

Tags: php, line-breaks

Sorry, I am a php beginner. I'd like to have a line break

```
$a = "apple \r\n orange \r\n banana";
```

display

```
echo $a;
```

This does not do the line breaks. I followed some of the answers already given and really the above should work. Why doesn't it? How can I make this come out like:

apple

orange

banana

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a line break within echo in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nl2br` function of php:

```
$a = "apple \r\n orange \r\n banana";
echo nl2br($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Break tag would do that job

```
<?php
 $str = "Hello world!";
 echo $str;
 echo "<br>What a nice day!";
 ?>
```

output:

```
Hello world!
What a nice day!
```

So in your case, it will be `$a = "apple <br> orange <br> banana"; echo $a`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<br>` tag for this . Try this

```
$a = "apple <br> orange <br> banana";
echo $a;
```

Output

```
apple 
orange 
banana
```

Answer (score 0):

As the browser interpretes your echo strings as html you could try to use `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're using such escape characters, it's better to use nl2br() function.

Refer to [nl2br() Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#refsect1-function.nl2br-examples)

```
$a = "apple \r\n orange \r\n banana";
echo nl2br($a);
```