# Getting CRLF from text input in php

Tags: php, html, newline, textinput

I am relatively new to web development. I have a simple text input and submit button in html.

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
<input type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-small" name="send" value="Send email" />
</div>
```

I get the value of the text input in php and `echo` it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{
    echo $_POST["sender"] . " \r\nThis was a test";
}
?>
```

Now I type `\r\nUser input` in text input. I intend the `echo` command to look like:

```
echo "\r\rUser input." . " \r\nThis was a test."
```

And when displayed, should look like:

```
User input. This was a test.
```

Instead the first `\r\n` prints as it is and only the second `\r\n` is interpreted as `CRLF`.

```
\r\nUser input. This was a test.
```

I've tried `'\r\n' "\r\n" \\r\\n` but non seem to work.

Note: I don't want actual line break in html, I know that in html line breaks are `<br />`. I want a line break in php string.

Comment: Have you tried `echo  nl2br ("User input. \n This was a test");` ? (found here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php))

Comment: @danny The code is part of a sample program to demonstrate php mail() vulnerability. I cannot add anything else to the code. I can only interact with it by typing values in html text input.

Comment: Alright, what about html entities? e.g. `&#13;` for a line break?

Comment: @danny Yup, tried &#13, &#10 and others. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is going to filter/encode/sanitize everything you enter in the text field, so you will have to find a way to make the browser generate CRLF for you.

One way would be to:

- use Firefox
- install extension `TamperData`
- use it to modify the text you send, e.g. inserting %0D%0A at the
  beginning; which is the URL-encoded version of \r\n